# Implement custom token-based authorization/authentication system

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I am trying to migrate one of our solution from a Laravel/PHP system to a .Net Core 2-based system. My main problem is regarding Authorization and Authentication.

I have 5 different apps that send REST queries to the Api (e.g. Web Browser, iOS Apps, Android Apps, etc.) and the way I currently handle authentication/authorization is as follows:

1. A user sends a Username/Password, as well as an App Id (e.g. 'Browser', 'iOS', etc.) and an App description (e.g. 'Chrome-Jacob', 'iPhone-7-Jacob').
2. If a Token already exists for the pair of App Id / App Description, it is returned. Otherwise, a new token is generated and saved in a Database table named 'Tokens'.
3. Each token can have a different matrix of permission, which is very granular (e.g. 'Users/ViewAll', 'Users/Create', 'Users/ViewOne', 'Users/ViewMe', etc.)
4. When a REST query is received with the token in the header, we look for the token's permission matrice in the database and try to see whether the intended feature to be accessed is authorised or not.

It seems that in Core 2, the intended use of token is through JWT. I'm not 100% comfortable with this approach, because I want the user to be able to see all tokens that were generated for his access, all associated permissions and the ability to simply revoke access to a token; whereas with a JWT, it is impossible to know who has what token, until they send it in a request.

My current implementation can generate any random token as long as it's unique in database; it doesn't necessitate any encryption algorithm.

What would be the best approach to replicate the system above in Core 2 ?

I find Microsoft's approach very good for simple applications but I am struggling to override the Authorize Attribute and get the granularity that I wish for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find Microsoft's approach very good for simple applications but I am struggling to override the Authorize Attribute and get the granularity that I wish for.

That's quite the opposite. Microsoft did not invent nor were close to the first to start using JWTs. You have taken something that is very common and made your own version of it, something that's not considered secure nor a good practice.

There are two ways to solve the problem at hand:

1. Using [Identity Server 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/), a free, open-source system made for ASP.NET Core, made by highly experienced security people, which provides you a customizable OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect system. With this, you would need to rework, some parts of the security of the applications, but you would be using industry standards.
   Note: this might not be too easy, but scales extremely well

   Identity server already gives you all the information about each application and which tokens are valid for which.
2. While you could do this by hand without too much trouble, I would suggest you to look at [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), the official framework for Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Core. Notice that, regarding how to know which tokens/logins are active, Identity recently adopted two interesting tables:

   - IdentityUserLogin: tells you what users logged in where/how
   - IdentityUserToken: gives you the tokens that have been provided for a given user.

All this said, it's common to add ASP.NET Core Identity to an Identity Server 4 application, given that the later is not for handling authorization.